# How does jmock and mockito create wrappers?

Tags: java, aop, mockito, jmock

For example, I have the following code:

```
SomeClass stub = Mockito.mock(SomeClass.class);
```

After that, stub is a normal implementation of SomeClass, but with its own behavior (default is to just throw some exception, but that's ok)

How can I do the same thing for my library? I would like to be able to wrap some classes, or even better instances with some wrap() method, to mix-in my behavior there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both jmock and Mockito (which uses jmock code) use cglib internally to create their stubs/proxies. See [`ClassImposterizer`](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/source/browse/src/org/mockito/internal/creation/jmock/ClassImposterizer.java?name=1.8.5).

For simple cases, you can use Java's [`Proxy`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) mechanism to create dynamic proxies (really just invocation handlers) of interfaces you want to stub or mock.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `proxy` design pattern. Proxy implements mocked interface / extends mocked class, so it can be casted to the mocked type. It can also delegate responsibility to the 'real implementation' if required. Usually, such proxy stub is created with a little mix of reflection.

Comment: not an actual answer - question was what to use - as in what framework/library etc, not how it works as a concept or what design pattern it is

Comment: The question was "How can I do the same thing for my library?" not "what particular class I need to use". And my answer is - use proxies - how they are created it doesn't matter. It can be done in dozens of ways...